# Design to manage paid subscription to services in an application?

Tags: java, oop, model-view-controller

Let's say I have a hypothetical paid application like stackoverflow. The application allows a user to do two things:

1. Post a question
2. Post an answer

This application charges $20 to buy a plan which allows posting 10 questions and 10 answers.

Technically, both the actions are exposed through completely different interfaces

```
interface Questions {
    postQuestion(String question);
}

interface Answers {
   postAnswer(int questionId, String answer); 
}
```

Both the services are accessible over web through different controllers. I need to keep track of how many questions and answers the user has posted, so that I can ask them to make a new purchase when the limit is reached, without delegating this task to the services.

For instance in Java, I need something like a map like `Map<Method,Integer>`, which keeps track of how many times each allowed method was successfully invoked. And, maintain this map by intercepting the calls to these services. This Map will also require database storage.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In your Customer DB you can add a `answerCounter` and a `questionCounter`.

When the customer registered set those value to 10.

Each time a service is called first check if the customer is allowed to call it by checking if `answerCounter` or `questionCounter` (depending on the request) is higher than 0.

If the customer is allowed to post the answer/question then decrement the `answerCounter` or `questionCounter` by 1.

If the customer paid a new pack increase those value by or to 10.

Comment: Thanks, that calls for each service to check if their method can be invoked. With many different services, it can get hard to make each service do the check for itself. Since also this is kind of a 'cross cutting' concern, I was looking to intercept the calls somehow and I can just configure which methods need to be intercepted. Does that make sense?

Comment: If you have many calls, then you can create 2 concurrentHashMap (one for each counter). When a customer connects load the current values in the maps. When his session ends save the values in the DB. During the customer journey, the DB won't be used, only your maps.